# ¿Como puedo hacer una funcion que elimine por completo una carpeta, las subcarpetas, y los items dentro?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo una Todo List usando el stack MERN. Quiero que cuando un usuario elimine una carpeta, se eliminen ademas todas las subcarpetas y los items que haya dentro pero no se como hacerlo. Este es el modelo de carpeta:

```
const folderSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    parent: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Folder'
    }
}, {timestamps: true})
```

Y lo que yo intente hacer es lo siguiente:

```
const removeFolderAndAllInside = folderId => {
    Folder.find({ parent: folderId}, (err, folderFound) => {
        if(folderFound.length > 0) {
            folderFound.map(item => {
                removeFolderAndAllInside(item._id);
                Todo.deleteMany({folder: item._id}, (error, deletedTodos) => {
                //Handle errors and deletedTodos
                })
            })
        } else {
            Todo.deleteMany({folder: folderFound._id}, (error, deletedTodos) => {
                //Handle errors and deletedTodos
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Y esta función la llamaria desde el controlador de eliminar carpeta. Pero en caso de que haya error durante el borrado de los todos o las carpetas no se como poder manejarlos de alguna forma. Nunca habia utilizado una funcion recursiva para eliminar objetos con mongoose

Aclaracion: Por carpeta me refiero a las carpetas donde se guardan los items del proyecto. La idea es que el usuario pueda crear "Carpetas" para guardar la lista de cosas para hacer y asi poder separarlas por temas.

Comment: que tiene que ver esto con mongodb?

Comment: Cuando te refieres a "eliminar carpeta y todo lo que hay dentro" ¿te estás refiriendo a documentos y subdocumentos de MongoDB?

Comment: En síntesis, sí te estás refiriendo a documentos y subdocumentos de MongoDB. Tal y como estaba redactada anteriormente la pregunta, sonaba a que te referías a _carpetas del sistema_.